# array inside of execute fails

Tags: php, pdo

Why this one works

```
    class xyz{
    private $_db;
            function __construct(){

        //database connection 
    }

    function abc($login,$pass,$email){
        $l = "login";
        $check = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE login = ?");
        $check->execute(array($login));
        $res1 = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        return var_dump($res1);
    }
}
```

And if i change the row selection for login to the variable the code return bool false

```
    class xyz{
    private $_db;
    function __construct(){

        //database connection 
    }

    function abc($login,$pass,$email){
        $l = "login";
        $check = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT userid FROM users WHERE ? = ?");
        $check->execute(array($l,$login));<<<<<-----THIS $l FAILS TO WORK
        $res1 = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        return var_dump($res1);
    }
}
```

What is the best way to do 3 exactly same queries with different row selections and their values?

Comment: Why would you want to pass the column name, it will treat is as a string : "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE 'login' = 'whatever'"

Comment: Because I want to check 2 colomns and I've thought maybe it would be better to use same prepeared query for them. Now I see That I have to chose other way to do it. I didn't know that effect of this statment would be "SELECT userid FROM users WHERE 'login' = 'whatever'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) before asking a question.
2. Among other things there is said "placeholder cannot represent an arbitrary part of the query, but a **complete data literal only**."
3. Identifiers have to be formatted **and** white-listed instead of parameterization. You can see an example in a tag wiki.
4. the best way to to do 3 exactly same queries with different row selections and their values is to run one query, setting all the conditions into it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about a simmular issues but didn't find anything usefull. I'll recheck this link.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot parametrise column names in prepared statements: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304

More also here: [Which tokens can be parameterized in PDO prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622521/which-tokens-can-be-parameterized-in-pdo-prepared-statements)