# PDO with LEFT JOIN and ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code

```
$query_search = $this->db->prepare("SELECT* FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table1.id=table2.id) WHERE table1.nome LIKE ?  ORDER BY ? DESC");
if($query_search->execute(array($cliente_procura."%",'table2.'.$ordem)))
{
   //code
}
```

But I'm having some problems with the `ORDER BY` clause.
How can I use PDO and make sure my tables are in the order I want?

Comment: What are the problems you are getting? Any errors ?

Comment: You can't bind field names like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binding the column names is not possible with prepared statements.

You need to use the age-old method of binding them in strings like this:

```
$query_search = $this->db->prepare(" SELECT * 
        FROM table1 
        LEFT JOIN table2 
            ON (table1.id=table2.id) 
        WHERE table1.nome 
        LIKE ?  
        ORDER BY table2." . $ordem . " DESC");
if( $query_search->execute( array($cliente_procura."%") ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Stackoverflow `PDO` tag wiki - https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

> **PDO Prepared statements and identifiers.**
>
> PDO has no placeholder for identifiers, so a developer must manually
> format them. To properly format an identifier, follow these two rules:
>
> *Enclose identifier in backticks.
> *Escape backticks inside by doubling them.

see - [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)
or - [Which tokens can be parameterized in PDO prepared statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622521/which-tokens-can-be-parameterized-in-pdo-prepared-statements)

see also this comment/example from the php manual - https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php#69304